# Redirect to views according to form selection

Tags: django, redirect, action, django-views

User registration in my application is performed in steps. After submitting the form, some validation is performed and then register_prompt view is called. It renders a form, with two options - 'ok' and 'cancel'. Clicking ok will run registration, and clicking cancel should redirect to main page. Problem is that no matter which of the two I choose, I'm redirected to .../user/registration/function_1_or_2_name with a blank page (although I have specified url in HttpResponseRedirect ). How can I make it work ?

```
def register_prompt(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response('user/data_operations/alert.html', context_instance=context)
```

Form loaded on alert.html :

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" onClick="this.form.action='{% url register_new %}'" value="Ok" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" onClick="this.form.action='{% url redirect_home %}'" value="Cancel" />
</form>
```

Redirect views (maybe there is a better way to do that ?):

```
def redirect_home(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def register_new(request):
    (... registration magic here ...)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/registration/complete/')
```

Finally url conf :

```
   url(r'^register_new/$', register_new, name="register_new"),
   url(r'^redirect_home/$', redirect_home, name="redirect_home"),
   url(r'^register_prompt/$', register_prompt, name="register_prompt"),
```

At first I was trying to add some abstract values to form's buttons (like 'action=ok'), and then catch them in register_prompt but it was a total disaster.

Comment: Are you getting any kinds of errors back when you get the blank page?  Have you tried to add some logging to see if you're making it to the views that you expect when the form is submitted?

Comment: yes, logs show that it's ok. I'm pretty sure, that error somehow comes from the 'action'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that `onClick=""` hack is really valid (I'll let someone else weigh in on that), but did you try just using normal links, to see if it's that or something else?

```
<a href="{% url register_new %}">OK</a>
<a href="{% url register_home %}">Cancel</a>
```

(Or check out `<button>` if you really want it to look like buttons. Or just use two `<form>`s, each with a separate `action=""` attributes.)

Hum, other than that... You say ".../user/registration/function_1_or_2_name" -- what exactly does the `{% url .. %}`s give you? Does it not add the final / (which you require in your patterns)?

> At first I was trying to add some
>   abstract values to form's buttons
>   (like 'action=ok'), and then catch
>   them in register_prompt but it was a
>   total disaster.

But you seem to want to manipulate the action attribute, so you can't catch anything in `register_prompt()`?

All in all I'd suggest you either use normal links, or actually handle the POST in the view that presented it:

```
def register_prompt(req):
    if 'ok' in req.POST:
        return register_new(req)
    if 'cancel' in req.POST:
        return register_cancel(req)
    return render_to_response('user/data_operations/alert.html',
                              context_instance=RequestContext(req))
```

Maybe something like that? Renaming your buttons to `ok` and `cancel`, and having the form post back to itself...

Comment: to be honest I haven't tried normal anchor tags, will check your propositions now.